# CSS / JS / jQuery - floating images of different size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grid-layout

I need to display images in a floating manner - but they come in 2 sizes, bigger one having the size of 4 smaller ones, here's a visual example:

http://minus.com/lbfCTUyQj0BHcf

I went ahead and used [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html), a cool plugin suggested in another SO question,
but it took me only so far:

http://minus.com/mkF3uSMeo/

As you can see there's still empty space.

Any ideas how to go about this?  Any solution helps, whether it's css, js, jquery - or even some other library (I figure I can adapt the solution to jquery).

The goal is to not have empty spaces, but everything filled - and the layout should remain fluid/liquid.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a test case of some sort?

Comment: Could you post the code for the first example. Using JSfiddle would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following html structure (which you will likely add classes via jquery), then the following css seems to work well to achieve what you want ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMm4y/3/); only tested in IE7-9 at present):

**HTML**

```
<img class="half top" />
<img class="half" />
<img class="full" />
```

**CSS**

```
.half,
.full {
    float: left;    
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.half {
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px;
}

.full {
    width: 90px;
    height: 130px;
}

.half.top + .half {
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```